# Why is Kotlin's memory footprint so large?

Tags: performance, kotlin

On my machine, Kotlin uses over 200MB of memory just to start up:

```
$ /usr/bin/time --format "%M kB" kotlin-1.7.0 -expression 0
0
222908 kB
```

This the worst memory footprint of all the languages I have tested (including Julia, which I thought was pretty bad). For comparison:

```
$ /usr/bin/time --format "%M kB" julia-1.7 -e0
152796 kB 
$ /usr/bin/time --format "%M kB" scala-3.1.2 zero.jar
71684 kB
$ /usr/bin/time --format "%M kB" racket-7.2 -e 0
67280 kB 
$ /usr/bin/time --format "%M kB" nodejs-10.21.0 -e 0
34752 kB 
$ /usr/bin/time --format "%M kB" java Zero // java 17.0.2 
33432 kB 
$ /usr/bin/time --format "%M kB" python-3.7.3 -c0
9248 kB 
$ /usr/bin/time --format "%M kB" ./zero.kexe // kotlin-1.7.0 native
2172 kB
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be launching kotlin apps using the `java` command? If so, what is the correct classpath to use?

Note: some of the tests above use source files which I haven't included, but simply return 0 from the main function, or an equivalent null-op.

Comment: Can you explain more about what exactly this test is that you're running? An empty console app? How did you bundle it, and with what VM? I also don't know what console commands you're running, having used Windows almost exclusively.

Comment: There is no point in comparing to anything else than Java. Kotlin runs inside JVM, so its initial memory footprint will be high. Still, according to you numbers it performs much worse than Java. It is crucial to provide information on what is your testing setup. Especially because you asked if you should launch kotlin apps using java command. Yes, sure, how else to run them?

Comment: The test is `-e 0` passed on the command line to the `kotlin` executable. `-e` is short for `-expression`.

Comment: `kotlin` executable is kind of the compiler, interactive shell and the runtime. Or something like that. This is like estimating the memory usage of the C app by measuring the gcc footprint. Compile the Kotlin code into jar and execute it using java executable.

Comment: When I precompile to a jar the memory footprint goes down to 45MB (executed with `kotlin`) or 36MB (executed with `java`), so I guess I was measuring the memory footprint of the compiler.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the amount of memory it takes in any particular run is not necessarily the amount it _needs_. There are JVM options to set the initial and maximum heap sizes, which could reduce the amount of memory used (at the cost of slightly reduced performance due to more frequent garbage collections), though of course there will be a limit below which it will run out of memory (and slightly above which it will run very slowly).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other commentors, when I precompile to a jar the memory footprint goes down to 45MB (executed with `kotlin`) or 36MB (executed with `java`). So effectively I was measuring the memory footprint of the compiler.

Aside: I also found an article describing [how to launch kotlin classes from the command line](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/run-class-from-command-line) with the correct classpath. This way, I can avoid the same mistake again by running kotlin apps with `java` instead of the multipurpose `kotlin` tool.